# ImageMagick - Resize to max width

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to resize an image to a max `width`. So I don't care about the height of the image, but I just want to always resize it to a specific width.

I'm certain I've done this before I just can't remember how I did it now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Seems this is the way it is done, noting that width is the first parameter.

```
convert -resize '100' image.png
```

For anyone else wondering about height, then you would do this:

```
convert -resize 'x100' image.png
```

Source: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

**Edit (Nov 2014):** Note that in the latest versions of ImageMagick you can no longer use quotes around the values as per Kevin Labécot's comment.

Comment: Note if you want to resize a bunch of images in-place (rather than creating new files) you can use `mogrify` command instead of `convert`

Comment: It seems setting size using quotes is not allowed anymore (invalid parameter). I had to remove the quotes and it works perfectly : `convert -resize 100 image.png`

Comment: @KevinLabécot Do you know what version of ImageMagick this changed occurred in at all? ...if not, do you know if doing it without quotes worked in older versions as well?

Comment: @Brett I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is ambiguous. Your titles asks to resize an image to a max width, but then you seem to say you want to resize the image to a specific width.

If you want to resize something to a max width of 600px (ie, any image with a width of less than 600px will be unaffected), use:

```
convert original_image.jpg -resize 600x\> result_image.jpg
```

Or, to directly modify the original image:

```
mogrify  -resize 600x\> original_image.jpg
```

If you'd like max height rather than max width:

```
convert original_image.jpg -resize x600\> result_image.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you just chasing the math to work out the correct aspect ratio?

```
$new_width = 400; // config
$image_width = 480; // loaded from image
$image_height = 786; // loaded from image
$new_height = $new_width * ($image_height / $image_width);
echo "$image_width x $image_height becomes $new_width x $new_height";
```

Comment: Dude, its should look like this: 
echo $image_width." x ".$image_height." becomes ".$new_width." x ".$new_height;

Comment: Double quotes parse php variables

Comment: I use smarty most of the time :3

Comment: @scuzzy No, I was chasing the flag to use within the command. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The way to resize to a given width in ImageMagick is:

```
convert image -resize Wx result
```

or just

```
convert image -resize W result
```

where W=width and is provided, but H=height is not included

See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry